# Continuous vs. Discrete Fourier Transform for representing a physical phenomenon

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform

This question is related to the differences between discrete and continuous Fourier Transform equations. Although I've found some good explanations about the difference in this forum, I cannot see how to make this connection in my problem. I have a physical phenomenon described by the equation:

$$u(t)=a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ib\omega}-1}{\omega^2}\overline{B}(\kappa)e^{-i\omega t}d \kappa$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants, $t$ is time in s, $\omega$ is the angular frequency in rad/s, $\kappa$ is the wavenumber in rad/m, and $\overline{B}(\kappa)$ is the Continuous Fourier Transform of a variable $B(x)$. The variable $x$ is the position in m. The relationship between $\omega$ and $\kappa$ is a wave speed, i.e., $\omega=c_0\kappa$, where $c_0$ is a constant in m/s. The Fourier Transform of $B(x)$ is

$$\overline{B}(\kappa) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}B(x)e^{i\kappa x}dx$$

My issue is that I don't know the function $B(x)$; I can only measure its samples in a given position step $\Delta x$. So, instead of having $B(x)$, I have $B[n]$ samples. If I need to know the samples $u[n]$, how these two equations would look like in the discrete world? And what would be the consequence/limitation for this representation?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to ask a question on physics.SE. Describe in few words your attempt on solution, but start with a direct request for a numerical recipe on solving your physical problem, clearly stated.

Comment: I can also ask them. Nevertheless, I still think this is a question more related to DSP because essentially, I have equations that model this phenomenon, and I would need to understand how to treat them once I have samples instead of knowing the continuous function. For example, I have the impression that the integral operator may become a sum operator, and the sum operator index would represent the samples and the frequencies. I just would like to understand how to jump from a continuos world (where I know my equations work) to discrete world  (where measurements will take place).